# Create multiple users from text file using Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I've tried for hours to create bulk users from a text file but I cant make it work. In the text file i have the following format:

```
John Smith:Student
```

The code:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=/home/knoppix/users.txt

GECOS=$(cat $FILE | cut -d: -f1)
USRGRP=$(cat $FILE | cut -d: -f2)

groupadd -f $USRGRP

echo "type username"
read USERNM
USERPW="123456"

useradd $USERNM -p $USERPW -g $USRGRP -c "$GECOS,$USRGRP" -d $HOME/$USERNM -s $USERSH -m
```

It is not working, when I tried to debug the bash script I think its not reading line by line, its grabbing all the content in the fields.

I'm missing a `do while` or `while IFS` or `for line` in `users.txt`. Something like this but I'm not expert help. also should I use newusers ir just useradd.

Comment: what the heck is `cat /dev/urandom` supposed to do!? :-) Please add comments to your code, i.e. `# descript of what this step is try to accomplish`. You can skip self-documenting things like `mv f f.bak`. Good luck

Comment: /dev/random is like mkpassword, im using it to randomize the password and the username

Comment: if theres only one line in the text file it works but if i have 100 lines it wont because im not reading each line, i need something like

do while read each line someone give me an example

Comment: Why not leave your questions up in case they'll help someone else?

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i need something like do while read each line

```
> outFile
while read var1 var2 var3 var4 ; do
  echo $var1 $var2 $var3 >> outFile
  echo $var4 >> outFile
done < /home/knoppix/users.txt
```

This assumes users.txt values are separated by spaces chars and that there are 4 words per line that you want to do some processing on.

If you values are separated with something beside space chars, for example the ':' char, then you have to tell the read command what to use as in IFS (InternalFieldSep), so

```
savIFS=${IFS}
> outFile
while IFS=":" read var1 var2 var3 var4 ; do
  echo $var1 $var2 $var3 >> outFile
  echo $var4 >> outFile
done < /home/knoppix/users.txt

IFS=${savIFS}
```

Also,

Code that is formed like

```
ECOS=$(cat $FILE | cut -d: -f1)
```

can be reduced to

```
ECOS=$( cut -d: -f1 $FILE )
```

Also note that for each line in $FILE, you will get a value, so if there are 3 lines of text, ECOS will be `ECOS="line1Val line2Val line3Val"`

I hope this helps.

Comment: i added a loop to the file but is creating unlimited accounts, how can i make the script stop when it reaches the last line, i addded.....while [ $# != EOF ]; do   (some expresion) EOF ;;

Comment: It's really better to update your question with your best work. Again, you're really close, but `$#` returns a number and will never return anything that can bey compared to EOF. Try `while [ $# != 0 ] ; and that assumes that some place in your code you 'consuming' arguments that reduce the value of `$#`, usually with `shift`. Good luck.